# Code Refactoring - Improve Duplicated Query Builder Calls for Readability

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

so I have the same piece of code repeating itself in many parts of my Model, however in different functions. Here is an example:

```
$records = AuditLogEntry::whereIn('context_type', ['Type1', 'Type2'])
        ->whereContextId($this->id)
        ->whereIn('event_type', [config('constants.audit_log.EVENT_TYPE_UPDATE'),
            config('constants.audit_log.EVENT_TYPE_CANCEL')])
        ->whereDate('created_at', '>', $date)
        ->select(['id', 'meta', 'event_type'])
        ->orderByDesc('created_at')
        ->get();
```

In another function doing something else I also have a similar block of code (pay attention on the last 4 lines of code):

```
$records2 = AuditLogEntry::whereContextType('Type3')
            ->whereEventType(config('constants.audit_log.EVENT_TYPE_EXERCISE'))
            ->whereIn('context_id', $contexts->toArray())
            ->whereDate('created_at', '>', $date)
            ->select(['meta', 'event_type'])
            ->orderByDesc('created_at')
            ->get();
```

So my idea was just to do a simple code refactoring on these lines:

```
 ->whereDate('created_at', '>', $date)
            ->select(['meta', 'event_type'])
            ->orderByDesc('created_at')
            ->get();
```

Because they are needed in many places in my model, I was trying to use callbacks to perform this code refactoring, something like this:

```
private function recordsQuery(string $date): Closure
{
    return function ($query) use ($date) {
        $query->whereDate('created_at', '>', $date)
            ->select(['meta', 'event_type'])
            ->orderByDesc('created_at')
            ->get();
    };
}
```

So then I could eliminate these 4 lines of code and have something like this:

```
$exercises = AuditLogEntry::whereContextType('Exercise')
            ->whereEventType(config('constants.audit_log.EVENT_TYPE_EXERCISE'))
            ->whereIn('context_id', $grantsExercised->pluck('id')->toArray())
            ->$this->recordsQuery(); /** This is not working, obviously but you guys can get the idea of what I'm trying to do */
```

So the problem is that I would like to use the chaining to improve the readability, I was thinking if maybe I could use Macros and extend the Query Builder including this new function. Of course I would like to hear your opinion guys to see if someone has a better idea.

Thanks for you help guys :)

Comment: Take a look at query scopes: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#local-scopes

Comment: You are the man @Jerodev. Please add an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a query scope to achieve this: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#local-scopes